# Error in Typing on Input Field Using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

My goal is to be able to open and navigate a web page based on the inputs I enter in Python.

Currently I am having issues inserting a string input into "Street #" field, and keep getting the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_key'
```

[image: Text Fields]

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r"C:...\firefox.exe")

# Open a Web Browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary = binary)

# Open the 1st Page
browser.get("http://sftreasurer.org/property-tax-payments")
elem_1stClick = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".ttx_button > div:nth-child(1)")
elem_1stClick.click() # Click on it

# On the 2nd Page
elem_streetNumber = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_tbStreetNumber")
elem_streetNumber.send_key("1230")
elem_2ndClick = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch")
elem_2ndClick()
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this line

```
elem_streetNumber = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_tbStreetNumber")
```

with this

```
elem_streetNumber = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_tbStreetNumber")
```

This is because `find_elements_by_css_selector()` returns list of web-elements while `find_element_by_css_selector()` returns just a single web-element

Comment: You are correct. Thanks. But when I modify the code, a different error message appears "NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: #ContentPlaceHolder1_tbStreetNumber". Should I modify the code according to your suggestion, or open a separate question?

Comment: Yes, these 2 issues are not related, so you'd better create new ticket